# ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host remote desktop

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I'm trying to connect to my work server using my macbook. in the morning it was working and now its not.

This is what im doing

```
ssh -vv muhammad@man.softwarehouse.com -L 1024:bolton:3389
```

This is the verbose

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to man.softwarehouse.com [111.111.111.111] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/muhammadnadat/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/muhammadnadat/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/muhammadnadat/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/muhammadnadat/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Also when I can connect when im using my friends wifi !

Comment: If it works in your friends network and doesn't in yours, is most likely an problem of your network. Do you have any barriers (firewall/proxies) in your network? or in the host configuration?

Comment: Check the verbose logs on the ssh _server_. They will tell you what has gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using TCP Wrappers for access control can cause the vague message above.

Check the contents of your `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` to ensure you are not blocking SSH.